# Foreign Keys As Composite Primary key

Tags: foreign-key, normalization

Can two non-key attributes of the same table be the composite primary key of another table??

In relation R(BCFGH) following set of FDs hold:

- B -> CFH
- CH -> G

Since CH -> G is transitive dependency in the above relation so in 3NF split the relation is divided into two sub-relations as follows:

- R1(BCFH)
- R2(CHG)
  and the image Relational Schema for R1 and R2 is [linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgWR1.png)

Now I want to know if C and H are the foreign keys in R1 or R2.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is stopping you from determining that? A FK is a set of columns that must appear elsewhere in a unique column set.

Comment: I just want to know that is it possible to take two attributes from the same column as foreign keys to another table where they act as composite primary key

Comment: I am a bit confused because the non-key attributes can have the same values for multiple rows

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please ask the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question that you want an answer to. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [mre] [ask] [help] Your last comment is not clear, it doesn't explain how the last part leads to something that confuses you.

Comment: When the composite primary key contains foreign keys from a single table, Isn't there a possibility of duplication?

Comment: "Please clarify via edits, not comments."